# Комбинирование изображений камер Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здраствуйте!
Вопрос следующий. Есть камера, по задумке интерфейс должен окружать окно, где происходит игровой процесс. Нужно, чтобы изображение геймплея (1), было в изображении камеры с интерфейсом (2). Предпологается, что это будут две отдельные камеры. Вот схема. Как это можно реализовать, через **cinemamachine** или можно обойтись обычной камерой? Подскажите, пожалуйста[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создай интерфейс с 1 камерой, после создай 2 камеру над геймплеем. Объедини их так, что бы геймплей был поверху от интерфейса. Все махинации с камерами есть в этом [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=28JTTXqMvOU/)

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу причин почему нельзя добиться ровно того же эфекта при помощи канваса.

Если создать канвас и сделать весь необходимый интерфейс на нем, а канвас настроить что бы показывался поверх изображения камеры оверлеем - будет ровно тот же эфект, только с одной камерой и меньшим количеством потребляемых ресурсов.